# BASH - How do I get the contents of a folder with a space in the name?

Tags: bash, variables

I can use the following to get the contents of a folder with no spaces:

`files=~/Movies/MyFolder/MySubfolder*`

But the following doesn't work, if the folder has a space in the name:

`files=~/Movies/My\ Folder/My\ Subfolder/*`

I'm trying to echo out the folders contents as follows:

```
for f in "$files"
do
    echo "$f"
done
```

I have also tried putting quotes around the path:

`files=~/"Movies/My Folder/My Subfolder"/*`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with this list of files?

Comment: Well the echo was just for testing, but my finish script uses FFMPEG to generate thumbnail files for XBMC, as they are home videos and so cant get pulled in from TheTVDB :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Works better, and recursively.
find ~/"Movies/My Folder/My Subfolder" -iname \*jpg | while read f ; do
    echo $f
done
```

Comment: Could this be adapted to look for certain files? E.g. *.jpg *.png etc

Comment: Could I just use Grep at the end of that ls statement?

Comment: ls "~/Movies/My Folder/My Subfolder/*jpg" or better, use find :-)

Comment: @squarefrog: Don't use `ls` - it's not intended for this purpose. Use `for f in "$HOME/Movies/My Folder/My Subfolder/"*` or `for f in ~"/Movies/My Folder/My Subfolder/"*.jpg` (two ways of doing the `$HOME` folder and with and without an extension).

Comment: Did you even see that it doesn't use for, but while? -1 for not understanding how this works. Also, for may not work when there are no files, and end up giving you "$HOME/Movies/My Folder/My Subfolder/"* when nothing exists. There are reasons why I've chosen what I've written.

Comment: `touch $'foo\nbar.jpg'` and see how your while loop deals with the file.

Comment: The find version picks it up rather nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array:

```
shopt -s nullglob   # If the folder is empty, don't treat * literally
files=(~/Movies/My\ Folder/My\ Subfolder/*)
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo $f
done
```

or, as Dennis says, just iterate over the glob directly (which I mistakenly thought wouldn't work):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in ~/Movies/My\ Folder/My\ Subfolder/*; do
    echo $f
done
```

Comment: No need for an array, just iterate over the glob directly.

Comment: This may or may not work. I created an empty folder to validate -`Karthiks-MacBook-Air:~ karthik$ files=(~/Movies/My\ Folder/My\ Subfolder/*)
Karthiks-MacBook-Air:~ karthik$ for f in "${files[@]}"; do
>     echo $f
> done
/Users/karthik/Movies/My Folder/My Subfolder/*`

Comment: If the folder is empty, the glob will be treated literally. You can execute "shopt -s nullglob" to make the glob generate an empty list instead.